# ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl when running gensim in R via reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm trying to import gensim from a conda environment via R with reticulate. The conda environment itself imports gensim fine, it's only when I interface using reticulate that I have the problem. The code below shows exactly what I'm running, the output, and the environment (it's Mint 19.1, which is Ubuntu 18.04)

I've searched in vain for anything that even relates to this, although I have also run:

`sudo apt install python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev`

Because I read that might help. I also ran:

`conda install urllib3` and was told it was already installed.

To add to my frustration, it runs fine on my Mint 18.3 box, but I can't for the life of me understand what the difference might be.

```
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv("hello", required = TRUE)

py_run_string("import gensim")
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) : 
  ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)
```

The output of `sessionInfo()` :

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 19.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello/lib/libmkl_rt.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.12

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0  Matrix_1.2-17   tools_3.6.0     Rcpp_1.0.1      grid_3.6.0      jsonlite_1.6    lattice_0.20-38

py_discover_config()

python:         /home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello/bin/python

libpython:      /home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello/lib/libpython3.7m.so

pythonhome:     /home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello:/home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello

version:        3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17)  [GCC 7.3.0]

numpy:          /home/chris/anaconda3/envs/hello/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy

numpy_version:  1.16.3

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error when running the code from RStudio. It turned out that it worked when installing RStudio within the conda environment. But when using RStudio installed as a deb package (/usr/bin/rstudio), it failed. So you might want to install R in the same conda environment that you’re using for gensim.